# Error during Netlist Generation in Simulink

Tags: fpga, simulink, xilinx, system-generator

I was trying to generate a netlist from a simple Model in simulink. I can run the simulation (using  sysgen).

When I try to  create a netlist , it throws an error :

> "
>   *** ERROR ***
>
> Errors occurred during netlist
>   generation. Error using ==>
>   xlProcBlockElaborateBMM at 19 synopsis
>   file 'C:\<..>\timing\synopsis' not
>   found  "

So, I tried to create a synopsis folder manually, and then It started throwing following error:

> *** ERROR ***
>
> Errors occurred during netlist
>   generation. Java exception occurred: 
>   com.xilinx.sysgen.netlist.NetlistInternal:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Kiran\timing\synopsis\synopsis
>   (Access is denied)
>       at com.xilinx.sysgen.netlist.XTable.valueOf(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at com.xilinx.sysgen.netlist.Block.fromXTable(Unknown
>   Source)

I tried running Matlab as Administrator, but with same outcome. Kindly let me know if I am missing something here:

So, here are the config details :

Matlab version :  Version 7.10       (R2010a)
Xilinx System Generator                               Version 12.2

I did not find any solutions in the Xilinx forums, so I am posting it here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not come across that one - it sounds like a horrible internal error.

It looks like you're creating a timing netlist - can you create any of the other option netlists?  It might provide different (more useful) error messages!

Other solutions are of the typically tedious form:

- Re-run the Xilinx System Generator Configurator
- try a different PC
- reinstall the Xilinx tools
- Log a WebCase

Sorry!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could workaround with this issue. I am trying to generate the netlist in another system But I am getting a new error. I am posting this here with complete information. Thanks again.